# Is there a difference between authentication as a use case and an actor that has that privilege?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

[image: First Diagram]
[image: Second Diagram]

The first UML diagram features a basic user interacting with an E-Commerce site, where authentication is explicitly included for actions like placing orders, adding to the cart, and checking out.

In the second diagram, I've streamlined the authentication process by introducing an "Authenticated User" actor. This eliminates the need for explicit authentication in each specific use case.

I want to know if this is possible and which process you recommend following.

I know that authentication isn't a use case, but I haven't found a specific example to make this comparison.

I asked my professors and they said that only the first diagram is applicable. Also i did some researches in the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Authenticate is not a use-case

First of all, `authenticate` is not really a use-case. It's like [`login`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/432766/209774).  You already know it, but I'll clarify for the  readers of this answer:

- From the use-case analysis point of view,  it's not a goal for the user. No user would buy a system just to authenticate. It's just a constraint necessary for certain behaviours to complete.
- From the strict UML point of view, a use-case

  > specifies a set of behaviors performed by that subject, which yields an **observable result** that is **of value** for Actors or other stakeholders

  But performing authentication may not necessarily be observable (for example if the authentication is performed via single sign on capability behind the scene) and the user may not value the result of the authentication on its own, but only the value of the other use cases for which authentication is a constraint. Of course there is some room of interpretation here.

- There is no order defined for use-cases.  Use cases are not meant to describe workflow, whereas both of your diagrams expect an order.

Last but not least,  more and more,  authentication is no longer performed in the system but provided by an external system that is an identity provider. In  this case, it may happens behind the scene without the user even knowing - one proof more that it's not a set of behavior performed in interaction with the user ;-) .

### What diagram alternative is more suitable

I strongly disagree with your professor: the first alternative is not the recommended one, because it's a functional decomposition of your use-cases.  While this is not forbidden in UML, it is seen as bad practice by leading authors such as [Bittner & Spence](https://books.google.com/books/about/Use_Case_Modeling.html?id=zvxfXvEcQjUC&redir_esc=y).

The second one is more elegant in this regard,  as your actor specialisation (which is fully legit) allows to see what an authenticated user can do and what a non-authenticated user can do.  The only flaw is the `authenticate` use-case. But if you'd remove it, it would still be correct and express your design intention.  How the authentication is managed,  is then a technical or a user-interface detail.

Some side-remarks:

- if you'd insist on keeping `authenticate`, then add at least an association with `User`
- you do not need the redundant association between `navigate products` and `Authenticated user`,  because this association is inherited from `User` (all what a user can do, the authenticated user can do as well)
- you should remove the arrows from the associations between actors and use-cases.  This old notation is no longer valid (even if you'll find many examples of it on the internet and in books, refers to the UML 2.5.1 specifications in case of doubt).

### A better way?

Use your second, diagram, but remove the `authenticate` use-case which is not one.

The authentication should either be a constraint, or some action to be performed (perhaps conditionally, e.g. if user is already authenticated).  This action would be a part of the activity diagram that describes the details behind a use-case.

Even better: **simplify further**, because there are only two real goals here :  `Navigate products` and `Buy products` The **add to cart**, **place order**, **checkout** are process steps or user interface details.

Comment: Thank you for the phenomenal answer. As for the 'authenticate' in the second diagram, it was a mistake, and I didn't notice it until after uploading. 
And, I really agree with everything you said about login and authentication not being use cases.

Comment: Even the added benefit for the use case "Navigate Products" is debatable.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Indeed. But I have a very practical opinion on this: yesterday I was looking for office furniture shops to replace my old office chair at home.  I wanted to see what kind of chairs each store offered, before going on-site to try them out. Some stores still don't provide their catalogue online - no way that I loose my time.  Some offered long PDF catalogues to download. Pfff. And some actually allowed to navigate their products according to multiple criteria.  This had real added value as it saved me time, and time is money.  Not sure for shop app, that I'll buy in the end ;-)

Comment: While using the system, the user may traverse various states: not yet authenticated, authenticated, privacy conditions (cookies etc) accepted, etc.  I think it is bad practice to define an actor subclass for this purpose. I think actor subclasses shall be used to define various types of user, like administrator, sales employee, customer etc.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl that is a valid point of view. However, since the invention of the state design pattern, we all know that inheritance is a valid way to design state dependent behavior, so OP's point of view is equally valid, especially if the intention is to highlight that users in different states could have different goals. Moreover, imho, the actor being outside one could wonder if we should manage their state ;-)